# Unity - Modify basic dissolve shader graph to dissolve from bottom up

Tags: unity, shaders

I have this dissolve shader made in shader graph which works fine, however I would like it to dissolve from bottom up, how would this be done?

[image]

Comment: `[Dissolve Amount]` -> `[1 - Dissolve Amount]`, maybe?

Comment: dissolve amount has nothing to do with what direction it dissolves in

Comment: Then I don't see anything that involves the direction.

Comment: There is nothing, thats what I would like help with, at least to get started